# How can i list the items in the raw folder in android?

Tags: android, listview

How can I list the items in the raw folder in android? I have added the items in the raw folder to a `ListView`, but the id's are displayed in the `ListView` instead of the mp3 files.

Code:

```
public class Listview extends ListActivity {

      public static ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +2131034112);
        Log.i("uri", ""+uri);

        int aInt=R.raw.a;
        int bInt=R.raw.b;
        int gInt=R.raw.g;

        String aString=Integer.toString(aInt);

        Log.i("aString", ""+aString);

         list1.add(aInt);
            list1.add(bInt);
            list1.add(gInt);

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.listview,list1));

        ListView listView = getListView();

        Log.i("value", ""+list1);

        /*listView.setAdapter(adapter)*/
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                 String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                  int [] resID= {R.raw.a,R.raw.b,R.raw.g};
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(Listview.this,resID[position]);

                  mediaPlayer.start();
                  Intent intent = new Intent (Listview.this,PlaySoloActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                       list1.clear();

            }
        });

    }


    }
```

Resultant output:

```
2131034112
2131034113
2131034114
```

Desired output:

```
a.mp3
b.mp3
g.mp3
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to get all resource names in raw dir. The only drawback is that it will return only names without extension, but if all your files have same extension and you know what you could add it.

```
private String[] getAllRawResources() {
    Field fields[] = R.raw.class.getDeclaredFields() ;
    String[] names = new String[fields.length] ;

    try {
        for( int i=0; i< fields.length; i++ ) {
            Field f = fields[i] ;
            names[i] = f.getName();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return names ;
}
```